# How do I create a Buckaroo package from a header-only library?

Tags: c++, buckaroo

Given a header-only library like this:

```
└── foo
    ├── bar.hpp
    └── foo.hpp
```

How can I package this using [Buckaroo](https://buckaroo.pm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Buckaroo Wiki Page](https://github.com/LoopPerfect/buckaroo/wiki/Creating-a-Package) mentions the process:

First, run `buckaroo init` to generate a `.buckconfig` and `buckaroo_macros.bzl`.

Then you will need to edit two files:

1. `BUCK` - it describes the build
2. `buckaroo.toml` - it describes your external dependencies

**BUCK:**

The following `BUCK` file packages your headers so that every file can be included via `#include <foo/*.hpp>`:

```py
cxx_library(
  name = 'foo',
  header_namespace = '', 
  exported_headers = glob(['foo/*.hpp']),
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
)
```

This is equivalent with:

```py
cxx_library(
  name = 'foo',
  header_namespace = '', 
  exported_headers = {
    'foo/foo.hpp': 'foo/foo.hpp',
    'foo/bar.hpp': 'foo/bar.hpp',
  },
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
)
```

This map describes how the path defined in `#include <a/b/c.h>` maps to the actual files in the file-system. As the include-path is identical to your file-system layout, keys and values are identical.

**buckaroo.toml**

To make the installation of your package convenient for consumers, it is recommended to explicitly list the public packages that should be exported by default in the targets section in `buckaroo.toml`

```
targets = [ "//:foo" ]
```

If you have external dependencies you may want to install them via 
`buckaroo add URL@VERSION`

and connect the dependencies in your `BUCK` file:

```py
load('//:buckaroo_macros.bzl', 'buckaroo_deps')

cxx_library(
  name = 'foo',
  // ...
  deps = buckaroo_deps(),
  visibility = ['PUBLIC'],
)
```